# MySQL - Select with COUNT returning a NULL row

Tags: mysql

**This works**

```
SELECT DISTINCT  b.b_id 
FROM             b INNER JOIN c 
ON               b.b_id=c.b_id  
WHERE            c.active='yes' AND b.featured='no'
```

**When the results should be 0 rows returned, this returns a null row with count = 0**

```
SELECT DISTINCT  b.b_id, COUNT(c.c_id) AS count
FROM             b INNER JOIN c 
ON               b.b_id=c.b_id  
WHERE            c.active='yes' AND b.featured='no'
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When you use an aggregate function (`COUNT`), you need to `GROUP BY` the non-aggregated column(s). MySQL shouldn't even allow that query, but it does which leads to unpredictable behavior...

Comment: ahh, ok, so i've removed the DISTINCT and appended GROUP by b.b_id at the end of the query. is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want a `left join` instead of an `inner join` since you want to return a count of 0 instead of a missing row when there is no matching `c` record for a given `b` record.

Also, you should include a `group by` when using an aggregate function, such as `count`.

```
SELECT
    b.b_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.c_id) AS count
FROM 
    b 
    LEFT JOIN c 
        ON b.b_id=c.b_id  
        AND c.active='yes' 
WHERE b.featured='no'
GROUP BY b.b_id
```

Comment: the "group by" clause makes it possible to return a NULL value, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `DISTINCT` *inside* `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT b.b_id, COUNT(DISTINCT c.c_id) AS count
FROM b
JOIN c ON b.b_id=c.b_id  
WHERE c.active='yes' 
AND b.featured='no'
GROUP BY 1
```

btw, please consider formatting your SQL like this, which is more readable IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to try  GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT.

```
    SELECT b.b_id, COUNT(c.c_id) AS count
    FROM 
    b INNER JOIN c 
    ON 
    b.b_id=c.b_id  
    WHERE 
    c.active='yes' 
    AND 
    b.featured='no'
    GROUP BY b.b_id
```