# Prevent count() returns "NULL" in mysql

Tags: mysql, count, null

I n my mysql query, I am taking the count of elements if it exists. It returns the actual count if the product exists, but returns `NULL` if there is no product. How could I return `0` if the value is null? I found [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970824/how-to-return-0-instead-of-null-when-using-count-in-mysql), [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743428/mysql-select-with-count-returning-a-null-row) threads relating to this issue. But none of them helps.

My query is

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS num
FROM
    table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id_fk
JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t3.id = t2.t3_id_fk
JOIN table4 AS t4 ON t4.id = t2.t4_id_fk
JOIN table 5 AS t5 ON t5.t2_id_fk = t2_id
WHERE pd.product_url = 'sample_product'
AND mcd.main_category_url = 'sample_category'
AND scd.sub_category_url = 'sample_sub_category'
AND mpd.merchant_prod_status = 'active'
AND pd.product_status = 'active'
AND mcd.main_category_status = 'active'
AND scd.sub_category_status = 'active'
GROUP BY t1.id
```

I also tried `IFNULL(count(*), 0)`. And it too give `NULL`

Please help me... any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you give example with your data structure and data?

Comment: sorry..these are large tables. :(

Comment: Ok please try with count(t1.id) instead of count(*);

Comment: @CharveeShah : already tried and it gives null. I also tried `if(count(*) = NULL,0,count(*))`. This works fine if there is count > 0. Otherwise again NULL

Comment: Have you tried COALESCE() function of mysql. It does same as IFNULL.

Comment: yeah...that s also `NULL`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552086/does-count-always-return-a-result see this link.It says that count() will never return null.

Answer (score 0):

You should encapsulate it:

```
SELECT IFNULL(num,0)
  FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS num
           FROM table1 AS t1
           JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id_fk
           JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t3.id = t2.t3_id_fk
           JOIN table4 AS t4 ON t4.id = t2.t4_id_fk
           JOIN table 5 AS t5 ON t5.t2_id_fk = t2_id
          WHERE pd.product_url = 'sample_product'
            AND mcd.main_category_url = 'sample_category'
            AND scd.sub_category_url = 'sample_sub_category'
            AND mpd.merchant_prod_status = 'active'
            AND pd.product_status = 'active'
            AND mcd.main_category_status = 'active'
            AND scd.sub_category_status = 'active'
       GROUP BY t1.id
      ) s
```

Comment: thak you for help..but it again returns null.. :(,  @Oscar Pérez

Comment: @Arun It is strange.... how are you executing this query? Directly from the mysql prompt?

Comment: I am using navicat for execute the query. Both navicat and php code returns null

Comment: Just to get sure: are you 100% sure that PHP return `NULL`? Remember that in PHP `0==NULL`... You should use  `===`

Comment: yeah.. I checked it at the sql section of my server too.

Comment: I say this because if you do `SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE 1=2;` it returns always 0, not `NULL`... Could you try to execute your query on a commandline mysql client ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57485/discussion-between-oscar-perez-and-arun).